# LM317 with a load of less than 1.5A

Tags: voltage-regulator

The LM317 is rated for "[in excess of 1.5A](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group1/a0/db/e6/9b/6f/9c/45/7b/CD00000455/files/CD00000455.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000455.pdf)", I have an application that will have a load current of about 300mA. Are there any drawbacks to using this particular IC?

This is my intended setup:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fofUVD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No, no drawbacks. The LM317 is a voltage regulator and it has some maximum ratings. One is current, "in excess of 1.5 A" means that it **can** supply a bit more than 1.5 A, so a 1.5 A application would be OK. The **load** determines the current, your load draws 300 mA so that is OK, it is not more than 1.5 A. Like power adapters, the voltage is set by the source and the current is set by the load. As long as the load does not require more current than the source can provide, it will work.

Comment: I see you are aiming at 3.3V. At 300mA, 5V input and ambient temp, 1.75V dropout is just too close to be an appropriate regulator.

Comment: @FakeMoustache no drawbacks until you get down to the minimum current (10mA according to Trevor's answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downsides:

1. Ancient technology
2. High drop out (about 1.75V at ambient temp and 300mA) so you need an input voltage at least that much higher than the output voltage.

[image]

3. Relatively high current draw even when not loaded

Advantages:

1. Ancient technology - there's tips and tricks and schematic examples for it all over the web.
2. Ancient technology - mounting a TO220 or TO3 part is easy, even for the mechanically challenged.
3. Can handle high currents and large difference between input and output (if you use a large enough heat sink)

Comment: I just took a screenshot of the dropout voltage graph at 300mA (1.5V ~ 1.75V at ambient temp), do you mind if I add that to your answer?

Comment: Go ahead.  I'm posting from my phone, and that kind of thing is a bit difficult.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance *In Exccess Of* is the guaranteed minimum current you can draw from it under normal circumstances.

From the spec sheet you can draw a lot more than that.
See table 6 for real numbers. 10mA is the minimum.

Your feedback resistors seem a bit low though.

Comment: That 240ohm Vout to Vadj is chosen low to a) sink min 5mA from output so that the part regulates even with no load and b) it has a relatively high adjust pin current. Ancient technology!

Answer (score 0):

Not yet mentioned : It may be that a part with a lower load rating costs less. Not always, since ancient technology often means widely available and multiple sourced, as long as it's not *too* ancient.